# How do I create the 'left navigating toolbar' like the QT Creator does

Tags: qt

I asked these questions because after saw the showcase of 'ADS' open source here:

https://github.com/githubuser0xFFFF/Qt-Advanced-Docking-System#getting-started--example

the ADS showcase is amazing, but it's not the point.
ADS provides a freely docking widget manager system, but I want to add the 'left navigation tool bar' to convenient for switch different workpenchs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to copy-paste that class from Qt Creator sources. It doesn’t come with Qt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I downloaded the Qt Creator source, but the class is too huge, it's very hard to find the CLASS. I hope someone who is familiar with the project, could indicate where are they.